# Django - Unable to Locate Template from within App

Tags: django

Ive following the steps for adding a template, but when i try and access my URL im getting:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /

My code is below. Also I have my app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings. And the template is located within the templates folder within my app.

**View**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

**Setting**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Layout:

[image: edit2]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

can you add this to the top of your settings if you havent:

```
import os
from pathlib import path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

it seems like the dirs argument is empty, could you add:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR), 'NAME_OF_TEMPLATE_FOLDER'],
```

Comment: could you add the structure of your project to your question please

Comment: which settings file are you changing, the app one or the whole project?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your `.html` file within, `templates/<app>/` 
Directory structure must be like,

```
+ lookup/
 ...
 + templates/
  + lookup/
   - home.html
```

**UPDATE**

try,

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'lookup/home.html', {})
```

This is what followed by Django.

Comment: Tried this has not fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had installed the app in the wrong place. I started from scratch and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your template directory in `TEMPLATES` :

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join((BASE_DIR),'lookup','template')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
```